# If I kill my horses will it spawn more horses in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found some horses on my server, but there not the type I want. Is there a way to get more to spawn? like if I were to kill my original spawned horses will more horses spawn?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/how-does-animal-spawning-work

Comment: Breed them w/ Golden Carrots

Comment: You might be misremembering a bit of advice about animal spawning—Slaughtering *all* animals in a large radius is necessary to even have a slim chance of new horses. Killing just one type of animal doesn't work to get more of that type.

Answer (score 4):

It is very unlikely for passive mobs to spawn in already generated chunks. It could happen, but it's just very unlikely to. What you should do is explore **new** chunks and find some more, then bring them to spawn and breed them so that there will be more.

In addition to what has been said, @SevenSidedDie pointed out that you will need to kill all the animals in a large radius for the *slim* chance that a new horse will spawn.